# Import data from current and future date only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to import fivethirtyeight data, but when trying to import the full link from the CSV file, it exceeds the limit allowed by google.

So ... I would like to know how I could filter so that only today's games and future dates are imported. From the games of past dates there is no value to me.

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-api/club/spi_matches.csv")
```

IMPORTDATA didn't work because it exceeds the spreadsheet limit, because it saves past game data since 2016, so the data list gets too big.

I just need the current date and future date games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

It seems that the size of CSV data is 4,183,375 bytes, and 32,101 rows and 22 columns. So how about putting the data using Google Apps Script? Unfortunately, this CSV cannot be put using the custom function, because of the large size.

From [the benchmark for importing CSV data to Spreadsheet](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7), when Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced from the method with `Utilities.parseCsv()` and `setValues()`. So in this answer, Sheets API is used for putting CSV values to Spreadsheet. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script 1:

**Before you use the following scripts, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).**

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-api/club/spi_matches.csv";
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {
    data: data,
    coordinate: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId()},
    delimiter: ","
  }}]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
}
```

- In this script, the CSV data is put from the cell "A1" of the active sheet.

#### Sample script 2:

If you cannot use Sheets API, you can also use the following script.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-api/club/spi_matches.csv";
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
}
```

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Importing CSV Data to Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Perfect mate! Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to filter games only from current and future dates ... But when I try to filter, it doesn't work, could you please help me? I tried to do it this way: ```=FILTER('Page1'!A2:A,'Page1'!A2:A>=TEXT(now(),"dd/mm/yyyy"))```

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. For your replying, I would like to support you. But I cannot understand about your situation from your comment. And the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.